# Can't reorder the menu in Gnome

Tags: fedora, gnome, icons, menu

I tried `gsettings reset org.gnome.shell app-picker-layout` and rebooting to see if that helped, but it didn't.

I can't reorder the items (e.g. drag and drop) in neither favourites or the menu itself. I have tried disabling all extensions etc. I was able to do this up until a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the GNOME team has decided to make a change in how this works. In case anyone else experiences this, the solution is to *click and hold for two seconds* before being able to drag and drop.